# How to to setup an optimization in MATLAB which gives new set of variables for each iteration of my problem?

Tags: matlab, optimization

In MATLAB, as far as I know, I should pass the handle of a cost function to the optimization function in order to optimize my problem. In my situation, I do not want to create a cost function and pass its handle to the optimization. I would like to setup an optimization and ask the optimization object for best new set of variables at each iteration. I, myself, calculate the cost and pass its value to the optimization object. I mean the algorithm might be as follows

1- setup the optimization object (optimization method, optimization sense, ...).
2- introduce the variables and their bounds and constraints to the optimization object
3- ask the optimization object for a set of variables
4- implement the variables to the physical black box and obtain the outputs
5- calculate the cost function for the monitored output
6- if the cost function does not satisfy my goal, inform the optimization object about the calculated value of the cost function and go to step 3.
7- end

As far as I checked the functions of MATLAB optimization toolbox, all of them need the handle of the cost function.

Comment: The optimisation might require 100s or 1000s of iterations, how do you imagine it being practical to have manual intervention as part of this process? You should aim to programmatically run the black box model and close the loop, or pre-compute outputs for the black box model over a mesh and base the cost function on some sort of interpolation of that so that the black box is not part of the optimisation loop

Comment: Yes, you are right. But I still want to know if MATLAB has any function for this kind of optimization problem. Otherwise, I have to implement an optimization method by myself.

Comment: What is the difference? Why do you think changing how the optimization algorithm is run would be helpful? What is it that you can’t accomplish with the standard optimization algorithms? Note that the objective function handle can be to a function as complex as you need it, including presenting a GUI that requests data from a user, or directly interfacing with a physical device.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a very good idea, but can't you write a function that displays its input variables and asks you to manually provide the cost using `input`?